# Applying wpf validation rules to a textbox inside a custom user control

Tags: wpf, validation, xaml

I have a custom control, inside of which I have a textbox.  I want to apply some custom validation rules that include passed parameters (e.g., to implement range checking).

I would like to apply the validation rule to the top-level custom control like so.  I have tried my best to trim out superfluous code to make my example more general, but please bear with me if I have not completely succeeded.  I am somewhat new to the idea of posting code in forums.

```xml
<ns_control:CustomControl PropertyName="Value from embedded textBox:"  
    Style="{StaticResource errorInTextBox}">
        <ns_control:CustomControl.PropertyValue>
            <Binding Path="PathX"
                     Mode="TwoWay">
                                    <Binding.ValidationRules>
                                        <validation:IntegerInputRule Max="100" />
                                    </Binding.ValidationRules>
            </Binding>
        </ns_control:CustomControl.PropertyValue>
</ns_control:CustomControl>
```

OK, so that's it for the invocation of the control.  My actual code has some stuff with Validation.ErrorTemplate being set to do something as well, but that seems superfluous to this example.  The Style, errorInTextBox, is at the heart of the heart of the matter, as it sets how I want the texbox inside of my custom control to act when the validation rule fails.  The best way I've been able to figure out how to do this so far is to use Style.Resources to apply the style I want to any textbox residing within my custom control.

```xml
        <Style x:Key="errorInTextBox"
           TargetType="Control">
        <Style.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError"
                             Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="ToolTip"
                                Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},
                                Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}" />
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush"
                                Value="Green" />
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Style.Resources>
    </Style>
```

The above does a tooltip and a change to the textbox's border if an error is found, or at least that's what I want it to do.  My main issue is with the Style.Trigger--that's my point of failure.  I want the trigger to be when Validation.HasError is true.  The problem is that since the validation rule is set against the custom control, and not the textbox inside of it, the textbox seems to have no knowledge of what the HasError value actually is.  I tried using a Validation.ErrorTemplate to modify the borderbrush property and the like, but the template does not seem to have access to the textbox's properties the way the Style.Resource I used above does and so it cannot modify the border around the textbox, etc.

Is there any way around this, or should I simply give up the idea of encapsulation and just define the textbox outright from scratch wherever I am using my custom controls in this fashion and I need validation?  Defining them right there would give me access to the textbox properties, but it would result in a lot of redudnant XAML and seems much less elegant than if I could get it working the way I want.

Thanks to any and all for your eyeballs and your advice.

Regards,
Vik

Answer (score 0):

From the question I'm not sure if you can tolerate validation rule being set on the control and not the text box.

If you can have the rule set on the control, then, in its `ControlTemplate`, give a name to the text box (I'll assume `x:Name="TextHolder"`). In `ControlTemplate.Triggers` add:

```
<Trigger Property="Validation.HasError"
         Value="True">
    <Setter TargetName="TextHolder"
            Property="ToolTip"
            Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},
            Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}" />
    <Setter TargetName="TextHolder"
            Property="BorderBrush"
            Value="Green" />
</Trigger>
```

This will check the validation on the control and if it fails the setters will access the properties of the text box.

---

If you have to have the rule to be set on the text box -

- Add a dependency property of type `ValidationRule` to the control.
- Get the text box from the template (`Template.FindName` from within `OnApplyTemplate` override).
- Get the binding for `Text` property of the text box (a bit tricky, don't remember the syntax right now).
- Add the validation rule from the property above to the binding.

Comment: Thank you for your insight and reply. I don't have any particular design objection to setting the validation rule against the control, but I'm not sure how to get the binding working properly, as there's no real data I want binded to the top level of the control.  As well, I'm not sure how the control template for the custom control would work for naming the textbox.  Wouldn't I have to move all the characteristics of the textbox inside of the control from my control xaml file and into the control template for that to work?  Thanks again.